# Change language on Windows 10 single language.

Tags: windows, installation

My pc was pre-installed windows 10 single language (pt - BR), how could I change the display language to en-UK?

I tried to download the Language pack and install from terminal

```
dism /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\lp.cab
```

but I got "The specified package is not applicable to this image".

Comment: This isn't really a programming question so doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow. It *may* be better off on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com)...

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue appears to be image, why don't you reinstall? Also, have you applied the most recent updates?